# Does ArangoDB supports cross-building for ARMv5?

Tags: arangodb

My target is an ARMv5 CPU, so I have to find out an nosql suits running it. The MongoDB stopped supports for ARMv5, so I come to ArangoDB.  Does it allow me cross-build and run on ARMv5?  Does anyone has some experience on this job?

Thanks in advance.
-woody

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no arangodb doesn't scale down to this target. Its V8 dependency will require ARMV7 at least.

For the ARM7 target will compile, but is currently not working completely.

However you can access it via a simple HTTP client - so a Client/Server architecture may better suit your needs.

For Embedded targets of that size SQLite tends to be the best solution.